# Run same test with multiple values - Dart

Tags: unit-testing, testing, dart

I need to run a test with different values, and in C# I would something like this

```cs
        [Theory]
        [InlineData("hello")]
        [InlineData("world")]
        public void my_test(string value)
        {
            var myClass = MyClass(value);
            //Assert...
        }
```

but in Dart I need to do:

```dart
    test('MyTest', () {
      var myClass1 = MyClass('hello');
      var myClass2 = MyClass('word');
      //Assert ...
    });
```

which seems like a little too verbose, I know I could do something like

```dart
      var values = ['hello', 'world'];
      values.forEach((value) { /* run test here*/});
```

but does not seem reliable either.

Is there any other way to run a single test with difference values in Dart?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not seem reliable"?  In general, you could wrap your call to `test(...)` with your own function and then call `my_test("hello"); my_test("world");`.

Comment: I mean that if one the text which is provided by the data fails there is not straightforward way to know which of the element failed the test. btw thanks for suggesting the "wrapping syntax"

Comment: In cases where I use loops to avoid duplicate test code, on each iteration I either pass a different test name when calling `test()` or pass a different value for `reason:` when calling `expect()`.